# calculation using dictionary keys and TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary and format is

```
key1: [list of number]

key2: [list of number]
```

etc ...

the keys is a number where key1 < key2 < etc...

I am trying to select the all the last `n`list and I want to calculate it.

```
x = 0

for something in dict:
    if something >= max(dict.keys()) - n:
        x += sum(dict[something]) // len(dict[something])
```

but I am getting :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
and it said the error come from the 'if something >= max(dict) - n:'
```

please help...

Comment: You need to be more concrete in your example. Take a look at how to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a mismatch type. For instance, let's say you have the following expression

```
1 - '1'
```

Python will rightfully complain.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Because the first operand is and integer and the seconde is a string.

Also keep in mind that

```
dict = {'1':[1,2,3,5,6], '2':[7,8,9,10,11]}
```

is not the same as

```
dict = {1:[1,2,3,5,6],2:[7,8,9,10,11]}
```

In the first case the keys are of type strings and in the seconde the are integers.

Using your code you can test it

`type(max(dict.keys()))` will output `str` will in the seconde it will output `int`.

So your operand do not have the same type they must both be integers in order to proceed with the calculation. I'm guesting that the error is from `max(dict.keys()) - n`.You should double check the declaration (the keys) of `dict`.